# See a serial port as a MIDI IN device

Tags: alsa, serial-port, midi

I have connected a MIDI device to my UART RX / serial port `/dev/ttyAMA0` using some electronics as [described here](http://www.midi.org/images/midihw.gif).
I have properly configured the right baud setting (31250 baud, etc.).

It works: I can open the serial port, read some data, and I see the data coming when I play notes on the MIDI keyboard.

**How to redirect this serial port into Linux's MIDI system ?** (ALSA / rtMidi or something else?)

Indeed, I would like that this MIDI input is handled by ALSA, instead of managing the raw data myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a driver that replaces the standard driver for the ISA UART 16550 chip on IBM-compatible PCs ([documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sound/alsa/serial-u16550.txt)), but this does not work on different architectures.

To connect an existing `/dev/tty*` device with ALSA, try a daemon such as [ttyMIDI](https://github.com/robelix/hard-dj/tree/master/ttymidi).

Comment: Re CL.! It's for a RaspberryPi UART RX (probably not UART 16550? => I tried modprobe snd-serial-u16550 => doesn't work : no device present).